# rails syntax error variable within a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm adding new SCSS to my application and getting the following error:

> Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$primary".

I've got this working on my local server, however it fails after deploy

```
.oauth {
  background-color: $primary;
  background: image-url('oauth-bg.svg') no-repeat center center ; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;

  &__logo img {
 max-width: 150px;
}
```

Application.scss

```
// @import 'vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap';
@import "variables";
@import "vendors";
@import "magnific-popup";

@import "navbar";
@import "dropzone";
@import "projects";

@import "home";
@import "typography";

@import "base/base";
@import "components/components";

@import "theme-charcoal";
@import "swiper";


// @import "style"; //this one should be loaded in the last place

/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self


*/

[class*="col-"],
.col {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
 padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
.row {
margin-left: -0.5rem !important;
margin-right: -0.5rem !important;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 2rem !important;
padding-right: 2rem !important;
}
```

Adding the SCSS file to show the order items

Comment: where is `$primary` defined?

Comment: background-color: $primary; is defined on the theme-charcoal.scss file

Comment: Ok so likely culprit is this is being included before that file, and so this variable is not yet defined.  You will have to change the order they get included in, can you share your application.css file?

Comment: @RockwellRice just added it then

Comment: So make sure `theme charcoal` is above whatever that other one is from